# Running HTML/JS site on android phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, qr-code

I'm trying to run an HTML5 QR code scanner on an android phone offline. I'm using this library 
https://github.com/schmich/instascan

I just copied the below code right from the documentation and it's working like a charm on my computer. When I copy the folder to my android 8 phone, I don't get anything when I open the file with chrome. I should be getting a prompt window to allow camera access but I don't. I tried running an alert() on the page to see if JS is running and it is. I was wondering if there were any other steps to be taken if order for this to work from a local folder on an android smartphone local storage. PS: I also checked to see the permissions manually,they were all set to ask first

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Instascan</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="instascan.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="preview"></video>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
      scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
        console.log(content);
      });
      Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
        if (cameras.length > 0) {
          scanner.start(cameras[0]);
        } else {
          console.error('No cameras found.');
        }
      }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you add the instascan.min.js to the phone as well? If yes did you add it to the same directory?

Comment: Yes I did. I have a folder with the index.html and the instascan.js. just copied the folder to the phone storage

Answer (score 1):

Instascan requires a secure connection **(HTTPS)**, so you just need to add https to the url at the beginning to request access to the camera, even if the site does not have the corresponding certificates.